# run-time check failure #2 for class object

Tags: c++, windows

working on a project and when I am passing a return value to the main function it is returning errors that I can find no answer too and it's returning the value when I just exit out of the console but when the input returns the main it throws these errors

'poker.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Daniel\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Project4\Debug\poker.exe'. Symbols loaded.

'poker.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'poker.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'poker.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'poker.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp120d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'poker.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr120d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'de' was corrupted.

The program '[5440] poker.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

it's mostly the run-time check failure that I don't understand as I've been told the PDB files don't matter but I don't know if I should worry about the error or not and if I should how to fix it

since the code is long I put it into paste bin http://pastebin.com/nrGBVyuj

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, "corrupted memory" generally means a buffer overflow, and what do you know, you have one right here:

```
class Deck
{
private:
        int deck[52];
        int cardsInDeck = 52;
public:
        Deck(){
                int nsetUpCounter = 0;
                cout << "setting up the deck one moment" << endl;

                while (nsetUpCounter <= 53){

                        deck[nsetUpCounter] = 1;
```

You're writing to `deck[52]` and `deck[53]` that don't exist, trashing some other object.  Luckily the debug build caught you so you can fix your bug.

Comment: Tools like [Application Verifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371695.aspx) can spot errors like this as they happen. The debug CRT reports errors much later.